# Save Loop result into a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I have a code with a loop:

```
while j < 25:
    print ('#',j, ":", head[head.index(minHead)-j])
    j = j + 1
```

That gives as result printed:

```
# 0 : 12.148057
# 1 : 15.776696999999999
# 2 : 28.555822
# 3 : 28.89765
# 4 : 28.923944999999996
# 5 : 28.950239
# 6 : 28.950239
# 7 : 28.950239
# 8 : 28.950239
# 9 : 28.923944999999996
# 10 : 28.923944999999996
# 11 : 28.923944999999996
# 12 : 28.923944999999996
# 13 : 28.923944999999996
# 14 : 28.923944999999996
# 15 : 28.923944999999996
# 16 : 28.923944999999996
# 17 : 28.923944999999996
# 18 : 28.923944999999996
# 19 : 28.923944999999996
# 20 : 28.923944999999996
# 21 : 28.950239
# 22 : 28.950239
# 23 : 28.950239
# 24 : 28.950239
```

Can I save all this #24 index values with a name in order to show all of them as info text inside a tkinter widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a variable to save the values from your while loop e.g.:

```
list_of_values = []
j = 0
while j < 25:
    string_to_save = '#',j, ":", j
    print (string_to_save)
    j = j + 1 # this can be written as j += 1
    list_of_values.append(string_to_save)
```

I removed the variables `head`, `minHead` etc. as your code doesn't define what these objects are. But the snippet above should be enough to get your on the right track.

If you have a separate problem with `tkinter` feel free to ask a separate question.

Comment: Thank you, it worked as a variable I was looking for. Indeed now I'll try to figure it out how to integrate this list in my tkinter info text. Thank you very much for the help!!